# Text Area default value from the clicked array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a simple array. Now on click, I want them to edit them using `textarea`.

But I want the default value of the text area to be taken from the clicked item. (Currently, I've set it as the first item in the array.)

Please also let me know if the question isn't clear.

My code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const namesArray = [
    { name: "Test1", id: "1" },
    { name: "Test2", id: "2" },
    { name: "Test3", id: "3" }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      {edit ? (
        <div>
          <div className="backdrop" />
          <div className="editalign">
            <div className="Edit">
              {/* Need the default value to be the one Clicked */}
              <textarea defaultValue={namesArray[0].name}></textarea>
              <button className="button" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>
                {" "}
                cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}

      <div className="App">
        {namesArray.map((x) => (
          <div key={x.id} onClick={() => setEdit(true)} className="namesArray">
            {x.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Sharing the sandbox link here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-nash-wydv2p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You'll need to track *which* element to edit in your flag, not just a boolean

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-edison-ol0jf8

Answer (score 0):

You can use another state to control default value on that textarea

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  //the default value state
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("");
  const namesArray = [
    { name: "Test1", id: "1" },
    { name: "Test2", id: "2" },
    { name: "Test3", id: "3" }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      {edit ? (
        <div>
          <div className="backdrop" />
          <div className="editalign">
            <div className="Edit">
              {/* Need the default value to be the one Clicked */}
              <textarea defaultValue={selectedValue}></textarea>
              <button className="button" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>
                {" "}
                cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}

      <div className="App">
        {namesArray.map((x) => (
          <div
            key={x.id}
            onClick={() => {
              setEdit(true);
              setSelectedValue(x.name);
            }}
            className="namesArray"
          >
            {x.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[The sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cherry-9u2mnw?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah like pilchard mentioned ....

tracking `id` for e.g. as below

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState({ action: false, id: null });
  const namesArray = [
    { name: "Test1", id: "1" },
    { name: "Test2", id: "2" },
    { name: "Test3", id: "3" },
  ];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {edit.action ? (
        <div>
          <div className="backdrop" />
          <div className="editalign">
            <div className="Edit">
              {/* Need the default value to be the one Clicked */}
              <textarea defaultValue={namesArray[edit.id - 1].name}></textarea>
              <button className="button" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>
                {" "}
                cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}

      <div className="App">
        {namesArray.map((x) => (
          <div
            onClick={() => setEdit({ action: true, id: x.id })}
            className="namesArray"
            key={x.name}
          >
            {x.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.namesArray {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.backdrop {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.Edit {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 2px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
.button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.editalign {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```